# How to reset a socket back to blocking mode (after I set it to nonblocking mode)?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, blocking, nonblocking

I have read this regarding setting a socket to non-blocking mode.

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#File-Status-Flags

Here is what I did:

```
static void setnonblocking(int sock)
{
    int opts;

    opts = fcntl(sock,F_GETFL);
    if (opts < 0) {
        perror("fcntl(F_GETFL)");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    opts = (opts | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fcntl(sock,F_SETFL,opts) < 0) {
        perror("fcntl(F_SETFL)");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return;
}
```

How can I set the socket back to Blocking mode? I don't see a O_BLOCK flag?

Thank you.

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18307077/514235) helps.

Answer (score 17):

Did you try clearing the O_NONBLOCK flag?

```
opts = opts & (~O_NONBLOCK)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a more cross-platform capable solution:

```
bool set_blocking_mode(int socket, bool is_blocking)
{
    bool ret = true;

#ifdef WIN32
    /// @note windows sockets are created in blocking mode by default
    // currently on windows, there is no easy way to obtain the socket's current blocking mode since WSAIsBlocking was deprecated
    u_long non_blocking = is_blocking ? 0 : 1;
    ret = NO_ERROR == ioctlsocket(socket, FIONBIO, &non_blocking);
#else
    const int flags = fcntl(socket, F_GETFL, 0);
    if ((flags & O_NONBLOCK) && !is_blocking) { info("set_blocking_mode(): socket was already in non-blocking mode"); return ret; }
    if (!(flags & O_NONBLOCK) && is_blocking) { info("set_blocking_mode(): socket was already in blocking mode"); return ret; }
    ret = 0 == fcntl(socket, F_SETFL, is_blocking ? flags ^ O_NONBLOCK : flags | O_NONBLOCK));
#endif

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Linux also has an `ioctl()` function that works like WIN32 `ioctlsocket()`.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Indeed, however my thinking was that the API for fcntl makes it clear how to obtain the current flags for the descriptor, and although I could have used it for the second call I was trying to save readers a potential second API lookup.

Comment: why the `const int &` parameter?

Comment: @MikeMB Just an artifact of where I extracted this sample from my codebase. Not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way to clear the flag:

```
opts ^= O_NONBLOCK;
```

This will toggle the non-blocking flag, i.e. disable non-blocking if currently enabled.

Comment: Toggling would do the wrong thing if it's already clear. So just clear it using `opts &= ~O_NONBLOCK;`. Simpler and safer.