# Setting time out for connect() function tcp socket programming in C breaks recv()

Tags: c, tcp

In my program If the server is not reachable the connect function take too much time. So i try to give time out to connect using select(). Now the problem is that when i try to receive data from server using recvfrom() i got error "EAGAIN". here is code used to connect and receive data from server.

```
int sock;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
int connectWithServer
{

    int status;

    struct timeval  timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = 10;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    sock = socket (AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    inet_pton(AF_INET,serverIP,&addr.sin_addr);

    fd_set set;
    FD_ZERO(&set);
    FD_SET(sock, &set);

    fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    if ( (status = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr))) == -1)
    {
        if ( errno != EINPROGRESS )
            return status;

    }
    status = select(sock+1, NULL, &set, NULL, &timeout);

    return status;
}


long int receiveResponse (void *response , unsigned int length)
{
    socklen_t sockLen = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    long int received = recvfrom(sock, response, length, 0,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,  &sockLen);
    printf("Received %ld bytes...  err %d\n",received, errno);

    return received;
}
```

Comment: `recvfrom` and `connect` doesn't match. First one is for UDP sockets, the latter is TCP related

Comment: but its working fine if there is no time out

Comment: yes it works but `from` parameter is useless since you know who's the peer. Anyway, it was just a suggestion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Setting time out for connect() function tcp socket programming in C is not working

Correction. Setting the connect timeout *is* working. What 'isn't working' is the subsequent `recvfrom()`, and that's because you left the socket in non-blocking mode and you don't know what to do with the resulting `EAGAIN.` So, either handle that, by using `select()` to tell you when the socket is ready to read, or else put the socket back into blocking mode after finishing the connect.

Answer (score 5):

You receive `EAGAIN` because there's no data to read from socket buffer and your socket was set as `nonblocking`. Since you're not connected with the peer, i'm not surprised with it.

Look at this from `man recvfrom`:

> If  no messages are available at the socket, the receive calls wait for a message to arrive, unless the socket is nonblocking  (see  fcntl(2)), in  which case the value -1 is returned and the external variable errno set to EAGAIN.  The receive calls normally return any  data  available, up to the requested amount, rather than waiting for receipt of the full amount requested.

Another case could be the following:

- *Your socket may be connected but you're too fast checking if something is received.* To avoid this, put another select before recvfrom in order to extract the packet from the socket buffer (calling `readfrom` or just `read`) only when your're sure you received something.

Comment: returning value from the select says it is connected

Comment: are you sure? in your description you told the peer is not reachable. Anyway... what's the return value of the select? did you test your socket was triggered with FD_ISSET?

Comment: "1" is returned from select()

Answer (score 5):

The first successful select means the connect operation is complete but *does not necessarily mean it succeed*, from [connect](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect) man page, you should check `SO_ERROR` to make sure it completed successfully

> It is possible to select(2) or poll(2) for completion by selecting the
>   socket for writing.  **After select(2) indicates writability, use
>   getsockopt(2) to read the SO_ERROR  option  at  level  SOL_SOCKET  to 
>   determine whether  connect() completed successfully** (SO_ERROR is zero)
>   or unsuccessfully (SO_ERROR is one of the usual error codes listed
>   here, explaining the reason for the failure).

So in your code you should do something like this:

```
int ret;
ret=select(sockfd+1, NULL, &wfds, NULL, NULL); //should use timeout
if(ret==1 && getSocketOpt(sockfd, SO_ERROR) ==0) {
    return 0; //successfully connected
}
```

Then, as mentioned in the other answer you should call select again before writing or reading from the socket.

Comment: Thanks for information... is there any alternate method for setting time out

Comment: @RAJESH yes I think signals could be used, but I believe select is the idiomatic way to do it, just make sure you check `SO_ERROR` after selecting for connect.

Comment: Great answer! 
May i know what is the recommended value for timeout here i.e for connection timeout?

Comment: If the `select()` returns 0 then it means that the socket timed out. If return -1 then it's an error. For >0, something interesting happened on the socket. Isn't it worth to decide based on that? Why do we need to check SO_ERROR (Are we checking for a corner case where the socket connected just on timeout)?

Answer (score 5):

The socket should be set to blocking mode again before calling recv().

```
fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, 0) & ~O_NONBLOCK);
```