# Turning on O_NONBLOCKING in C on LINUX

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

***Background****
I am new to TCP so I have question that may be a bit basic. I am trying to turn on O_NONBLOCK on a socket that is receiving data. Up until now I have tried to different ways to set O_NONBLOCK, itcl() and fcntl(). Right now I am trying to get fcntl() to work.

My Question: Are you supposed to set O_NONBLOCK before you connect the socket or after?

**my current implementation of fcntl() is based off off the link before the code:

[How to reset a socket back to blocking mode (after I set it to nonblocking mode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149798/how-to-reset-a-socket-back-to-blocking-mode-after-i-set-it-to-nonblocking-mode)

```
//set socket to NONBlocking
on = fcntl(Socket,F_GETFL);
on = (on | O_NONBLOCK);
if(fcntl(Socket,F_SETFL,on) < 0)
    {
       perror("turning NONBLOCKING on failed\n");
    }

// DO CONNECT
rc = connect()
```

Thank you for taking the time to look at this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are supposed to set `O_NONBLOCK` whenever you want. If you do it before `connect`, then `connect` will be non-blocking as well (returning `EINPROGRESS`; you can `select` or `poll` for writable state to wait for its completion).

Comment: is there a way to check and make sure it is on?

Comment: do you want to check or to make sure it is on? anyway, that's what you already do with `F_GETFL` (you can insert "check" logic after `on = fcntl(...)`).

Comment: When I turn O_NONBLOCK on i get "Invalid argument" and "I/O error" (22, 5). Could turning on O_NONBLOCK mess up my connection? When I comment out `on = fcntl(Socket,F_GETFL);` and `on = (on | O_NONBLOCK);` it works.

Comment: Where do you get those errors? Certainly not from `fcntl`? Can you provide a [complete example](http://sscce.org)?

Answer (score 0):

And to answer part two, use the same code but turn the O_NONBLOCK bit off instead of on.